# Issue with Postman

Tags: postman

I created Postman POST API call to my backend which is running on AWS server

```sh
header: Content-Type application/json, 
body: raw JSON
```

and I got proper response.
My tester (it is a person which works remotely) does the same thing and gets wrong API response (not what we expected).

I tried to make the same test case on 4 another computers in our company and got the same PROPER response.
What can be wrong with my tester's Postman?

Comment: Postman gives you the raw request to play with. (I think you can even export a Postman request to send to someone else?) Compare the two, using something like `diff`, and look for subtle differences. It might help if you indicated *how* the responses differ.

Comment: I sent the same info (body) to my tester

Comment: The body isn't the only important bit, though. How about the headers?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some kind of firewall or list of permitted IPs that you would need to add your Remote workers IP to?

Comment: if that is the case you might need to do some weird stuff with a vpn and port forwarding

Comment: No, that is not my case.